# How can I extract data from the MongoDB Stitch database without receiving "Promise pending"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, azure-functions, mongodb-stitch

I would like to write an API for the MongoDB Stitch database that would be on Azure Functions.
Therefore, I would like to get all records from all collections to be able to "throw them on the screen".

I've tried in many ways but it still has the same error - "Promise { < pending > }".

My code:

```js
const {
    Stitch,
    RemoteMongoClient,
    AnonymousCredential,
} = require('mongodb-stitch-server-sdk');

const client = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('APP_ID');
client.auth.loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential()).then(user => {
    // console.log(user);
    // client.close();
}).catch(err => {
    // console.log(err);
    // client.close();
})

const db = client
    .getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, 'CLUSTER_ID')
    .db('main');

const collections = [
    'dogs',
    'cats',
    'birds',
];

// Creating an empty Json object
// const r_obj = JSON.parse('[]');

for (let collection of collections) {
    const r = db.collection(collection)

    r.find({})
        .toArray()
        .then(results => {
            console.log(`${results.length} documents in ${collection} collection`);
            // Adding other collections to the object
            // r_obj[collection].push(JSON.stringify(results));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

// Later, returning it as an exit in Azure Functions
// console.log(r_obj);

client.close()
```

The database connection is working:

```
16 documents in cats collection
32 documents in dogs collection
334 documents in birds collection
```

Is there an easier way to get all records from all collections? But only something that can be obtained in Azure Function - NodeJs.

Comment: Could you please share the actual function code itself?

Comment: Already working? What function?

Comment: You've mentioned a promise being returned. Is this in a function that you are trying out already? Or you would want to convert this code into a function app?

Comment: Could you clarify which lines is returning `Promise {<pending>}` ? Generally this means that a promise has not been resolved. Either use `then()` or `await`